# In Facebook I can't see the option to hide groups from my profile, in "manage sections"

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

Suppose I am a member of some public groups. But I don't want people, be it friends or 'everyone', to see a list of all public groups that I am in.  Only I should see a list of all public groups that I am in.

I have read that there is an option for "Groups" in "more....manage sections."

[image]

I see no Groups option here looking at this pic below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, go to the menu then go down to settings and privacy and vlick settings,then scroll down to followers and public content

Comment: please include pictures  like I did in my question

Answer (score 0):

Go to your profile. Click the "More" dropdown menu. Select "Manage Sections". Uncheck the Groups located near the bottom of the list.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a "Manage Sections" part anymore. If I instead click on "Groups" there doesn't appear to be anywhere to change the settings.

Answer (score -3):

1. Login to Facebook
2. Go to your profile page. Look in bottom right of Cover Photo for "More" Option.
3. Click on "**More**" and select "**Groups**" from the drop-down
4. Click on ***pencil icon button*** near "**+ Create Group**" button
5. Click on "**Hide Section**" from the drop-down. Done.